# Difference between a semicolon and a new line in bash ("source rcfile; foo" vs. "source rcfile<NEWLINE>foo" where "foo" is an alias defined in rcfile)

Tags: bash

I thought that giving a semicolon in bash is the same as giving a new line, just combining multiple lines.

However, with `alias sudo='sudo -i'` in the `.bashrc` file, the below result doesn't seem to work as I expected:

```
USER@HOST:~:$ cat tmp-1.sh
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc; sudo env | grep PATH

USER@HOST:~:$ cat tmp-2.sh
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
sudo env | grep PATH

USER@HOST:~:$ ./tmp-1.sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

USER@HOST:~:$ ./tmp-2.sh
PATH=/home1/client/bin:/usr/python-3.8.2-r2/bin:/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

What's the difference between these two?

Comment: Alias definitions don't take effect until the complete command (a command which is delimited from others by a line break) that contains them returns. I didn't know this applied to `source` as well. Interesting

Comment: Okay, then does it mean that using semicolon doesn't make return, but linebreak does?

Comment: Kind of. `a; b` isn't executed until both `a` and `b` are parsed, if you change `;` to line break, they are parsed and executed separately. In `alias a=b; a`, `a` isn't substituted with `b` because `alias a=b` doesn't take effect until that entire line is parsed and executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in your comment:

> `alias sudo='sudo -i'`  is in `.bashrc` file

According to `man bash`:

> The  rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat confusing.  Bash always reads at
> least one complete line of input, and all lines that make up a compound command, before executing any
> of  the  commands on that line or the compound command. **Aliases are expanded when a command is read,
> not when it is executed.  Therefore, an alias definition appearing on the same line as  another  command  does  not  take  effect until the next line of input is read.** The commands following the alias
> definition on that line are not affected by the new alias.  This behavior is also an issue when functions  are  executed.  Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read, not when the function
> is executed, because a function definition is itself a command.  As a consequence, aliases defined in
> a  function  are  not  available until after that function is executed. **To be safe, always put alias
> definitions on a separate line, and do not use alias in compound commands.**
>
> For almost every purpose, **aliases are superseded by shell functions.**